# What's the meaning of "sting" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I watch the show Bojack Horseman S01E08, there's a sentence: "Herb Kazzaz, the show's creator, was caught tonight in an LAPD sting on public indecency. " What's the meaning of the word "sting" in this context?

Comment: Oxford on [sting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sting) -- see sense 2.

Comment: Go with Edwin, Andrew, et al.

First please ask your dictionaries and thesauruses, if not yur serach engine and if they all fail you, come back here.

Comment: I'm sorry for neglecting the help center. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [sting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sting) was originally a confidence trick that was used to deceive people in order to take their money.

Since then, (perhaps because of the popularity of the movie) it is come to be used for any deceptive operation, in particular [law enforcement operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_operation) where the police pretend to be criminals or victims in order to trick the criminals they are after.

Comment: Yes, the correct answer, but to a question lacking any reasonable research, and itself lacking attribution. If you'd reached 1000 rep, I'd have downvoted.

Comment: Why would reaching 1000 make a difference?

Comment: It's an arbitrary figure; one expects people to adjust to not 'answering' unresearched (where research may be reasonably expected) &/or ELL-standard questions by about then.